# Missing whitespace in align environment

Tags: align

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
  \varphi = & \{ ... \} \\
       \cup & \{ ... \} 
\end{align*}
```

In the output, there is no whitespace between = and { as well as between \cup 
How can I fix this?

For now I just put \text{ } but I think this is not a good solution.

Edit: I want to align the lines at the "{" symbol.

Comment: The `&` should be on the left side of the alignment symbol, i.e. `&=`.

Comment: i want the lines to align at the "{"

Comment: Use `={}&` in the first line and `{}\cup{}` in the second line.

Comment: @egreg i think i did not understand exactly what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `={}` and `{}\cup{}` in order to get the right spacing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  \varphi ={} & \{ ... \} \\
     {}\cup{} & \{ ... \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I used `aligned` which is conceptually better, but also a single `align*` could go (there are some slight differences, though).

[image]

Where's the problem? TeX adds spacing around relation and operation symbols based on what they have in front and after. Each cell of an alignment forms a formula on its own. Thus you get

> `\varphi` “thick space” `=`

in the first line, but no space around the `\cup` symbol in the second line, because it has nothing fore and aft. By adding empty objects, the correct spacing is restored.

Exception: in the even numbered columns of an `align` or `aligned` an initial `{}` is implicitly added. This is how `x &= y` gets the correct spacing.

Comment: okay that works, thank you. But why is it like this? Is the {}..{} a kind of hack? Why does latex fail to put the whitespaces whitout that?

Comment: @T_01 I added some comments.

Comment: So this apply to equations that have and `\implies` (or `\iff`)? Because these symbols have space around. Or should we use its alternative, namely `\Longrightarrow`, `\Longleftarrow` etc?

Comment: @manooooh Simply don’t use those spaced symbols in such a context

Comment: why we should not use them? how to write such things else?

Comment: @T_01 Look for `\implies` and `\iff` in the LaTeX manual: you'll not find them.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered whether you might be interested by this different layout (unless I misunderstand what you're after):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \varphi = {}&\eqmathbox{\{ ... \}} \\[-1ex]
 & \eqmathbox{\cup} \\[-1.5ex]
       & \{ ... \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not, but this is good to know. Thank you.